# capture only the leaf nodes when the parent node gets selected in angular-ivh-treeview

Tags: javascript, angularjs, treeview

I've managed to implement almost everything that I wanted with the treeview but could not able to capture only the leaf nodes whenever the parent node getting selected, So I only need the leaf node objects to be added on my array of selected nodes at any type of selections like below:

case 1: on selection of a leaf node

case 2: on selection of the immediate parent node of a set of leaf nodes

case 3: on selection of the last left leaf node
etc... etc..

```
<div ivh-treeview="demo.stuff"
     ivh-treeview-expand-to-depth="-1"
     ivh-treeview-on-cb-change="demo.updateSelection()">
</div>

$scope.demo.updateSelection = function() {
    $scope.selectedNodes.length = 0;
        ivhTreeviewBfs($scope.demo.stuff, function(node) {
          if(node.selected) {
              $scope.selectedNodes.push(node);
          }
    });  
}
```

With these above code, the entire hierarchy is getting added into my selected nodes array as soon as the parent node gets selected.

Answer (score 0):

`ivhTreeviewBfs` won't tell you directly if a given node is a leaf or not but you can check, e.g.:

```
if(node.selected && !(node.children || []).length) {
     /* it's a selected leaf! */
}
```

Also, a super minor thing but keep in mind you can use `ivhTreeviewOptionsProvider` if you don't want to hardcode properties like `selected` and `children`.